# kdb/q How to append a list to a table?

Tags: list, append, kdb

I have a table like this:

nameTable

| Name | Included |
| --- | --- |
| Ann | 1 |
| Bob | 0 |
| Cat | 1 |

I have a function that gets the "bits" from the Included? column:

```
// get the bits
fGetBits:{[nameTable]
  nameTable: select Included from nameTable;
  //BitsTable
  value flip nameTable}
```

This returns the following, of type 0h:

```
1 0 1
```

My question is how can I then take this 0h list and add it back to the Included column of the nameTable table, replacing the current values?

So for example, if I had the following:

```
0 1 1
```

I want my table to now look like this:

| Name | Included |
| --- | --- |
| Ann | 0 |
| Bob | 1 |
| Cat | 1 |

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also worth mentioning a simple `update` statement https://code.kx.com/q/ref/update/

```
q)update Included:011b from([] Name:`Ann`Bob`Cat;Included:101b)
Name Included
-------------
Ann  0
Bob  1
Cat  1
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little hard to follow but:

- If you want to extract a single column as a list use `exec`

  - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/exec/
  - Or simply index `` tableName[`columnName] ``
- You can update the values in a column using in place assigment

  - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/assign/
  - `tableName[columnName]:newListValues`

```
q)nameTable:([] Name:`Ann`Bob`Cat;Included:101b)
q)nameTable
Name Included
-------------
Ann  1
Bob  0
Cat  1
q)exec Included from nameTable
101b
q)type exec Included from nameTable
1h
q)nameTable[`Included]:011b
q)nameTable
Name Included
-------------
Ann  0
Bob  1
Cat  1
q)
```

Comment: Wow this is great. I didn't know about exec but this seems much better than what I was trying to do above, plus it actually returns a list type (rather than 0h for me). Thanks a lot for the help.